# Connecting with PnP PowerShell(without username and password)

Tags: sharepoint-online, azure-connect

Is it possible to connect a site of SharePoint without creditiantials(Username, Password, pre-stored credentials using the Secrets Management, Ref. Link: https://pnp.github.io/powershell/articles/authentication.html )? Because I have required permissions for Azure AD App.

Kind Regards,
Sezgin Tabak

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could you could refer to the below documentation to use AAD App for authentication with PnP PowerShell:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/solution-guidance/security-apponly-azuread

I have also answered your question here, please check it:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/311751/azure-ad-authentication-and-authorization-using-th.html